# Count values by group in R dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataframe in R `df` like this:

```
PROD           STORE         WEEK
13700023740   227587          1534
13700023740   227588          1534
13700023740   227589          1534
13700023740   227590          1534
13700023740   227591          1534
13700023740   227588          1535
13700023740   227589          1535
13700023740   227590          1535
13700023740   227591          1535
13700023740   227592          1535
13700023740   227593          1535
13700023740   227594          1535
13700023740   227591          1536
13700023740   227592          1536
13700023740   227593          1536
13700023740   227594          1536
13700023740   227595          1536
13700023740   227596          1536
13700023740   227597          1536
13700023740   227598          1536
13700023740   227599          1536
13700023740   227600          1536
13700023740   227596          1537
13700023740   227597          1537
13700023740   227598          1537
13700023740   227599          1537
13700023740   227600          1537
13700023740   227601          1537
13700023740   227602          1537
13700023740   227603          1537
13700023740   227604          1537
13700023740   227605          1537
13700023740   227606          1537
13700023740   227607          1537
13700023740   227608          1537
13700023740   227609          1537
13700023740   227610          1537
```

`PROD` refers to product id, `STORE` refers to store id and `WEEK` is for week. I want to create a new data frame `new_df` using `group_by` `PROD` and `WEEK` with three columns `Entry`, `Exit`, and `Total`. `Entry` should give the count of new stores `PROD` enters in a particular week. `Exit` should give the count of stores `PROD` exited in that week. `Total` should give the total number of stores `PROD` is available in that week. The expected sample output for the above data snippet is as follows:

```
>new_df

PROD          WEEK     Entry     Exit     Total
13700023740   1534      5         0        5
13700023740   1535      3         1        7
13700023740   1536      6         3        10
13700023740   1537      10        5        15
```

I figured out how to get the counts in column `Total` using the following:

```
df %>% group_by(PROD,WEEK) %>% summarise(Total = n_distinct(STORE))
```

Can someone suggest how to get the other two columns?

**Major Edit**: Link to real data set included and comments integrated into question (Not removing the sample data from original post to give the full perspective on the discussion with @Moody_Mudskipper)

Further to the discussions in the comments section, I am attaching the real data set [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1PELW_46l2RkAJwT0mq9rp6fmCBxQuZLV) because the sample data in original post did not capture some key aspects. It is .rda file.

1) The `WEEK` values are not always continuous for a `PROD`-`STORE` combination.

2) The `STORE` values may reappear for a `PROD` after missing in a particular `WEEK`. Since it is a sales transaction data, if there is no sales for `PROD` in a `WEEK` in a `STORE`, then that `STORE` value does not appear for corresponding `WEEK`, but could appear in latter weeks. E.g, for `PROD` 13700023740, `STORE` 227587 is missing in `WEEK` 1535, but may have 227587 in `WEEK` 1545, 1550 etc. The maximum possible value of `WEEK` is 1739. So, any new value of `STORE` for weeks on or before 1739 is an entry count for `PROD`.

3) To count exit, the `WEEK` after the last `WEEK` which has a `STORE` value should be treated as the exit `WEEK`. E.g., if the final `WEEK` for `STORE` 227587 for `PROD` 13700023740 is 1630, then we can consider 1631 as the exit week for `STORE` 227587. Here again, the max possible `WEEK` for any `PROD`-`STORE` combination is 1739.

Comment: can you explain how to get 3 and 1 on second line ?

Comment: please see answer below, I just don't obtain 10 (and a count of 15) in the last row

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper I think you missed the last three lines from my sample data, so you go a different result. Otherwise, your solution works on the sample data. But, when I use the code on my real dataset, which is quite large, I think there is some issue with the `Exit` column. I am trying to figure out that. What exactly does the last `mutate` command in your solution do?

Comment: Solution doesn't work in my real data set with than 700K+ rows. Only the `Total` column returns the values that I desire. Sorry, maybe I oversimplified it to create the sample data. Not sure how to share the real data. There are two key differences between real and sample data - 1) the `WEEK` values are not always continuous for a `PROD`-`STORE` combination 2) the `STORE` values may reappear for a `PROD` after missing in a particular `WEEK`. E.g, for `PROD` 13700023740, `STORE` 227587 is missing in `WEEK` 1535, but may have 227587 in `WEEK` 1536 etc. Could this be a problem in your solution?

Comment: For 1) it's not clear to me which week should have the "exit" flag then, the real next week or the next available week ? My solution should do the latter. For 2) do you mean that a product can exit and reenter? This is not supported by my solution. Before anything, try to rerun it after sorting the data by week, if for some reason it's not sorted it won't work

Comment: No luck even after sorting by `WEEK`. For 2) Yes. Actually it is a sales transaction data. So, if there is no sales for `PROD` in a `WEEK` in a `STORE`, then that `STORE` value does not appear for corresponding `WEEK`, but could appear in latter weeks. I know that the maximum possible value of `WEEK` is 1739. So, any new value of `STORE` for weeks on or before 1739 is an entry count for `PROD` For 1) I realize its a bit complicated. Explained in the next comment.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177067/discussion-between-rnovice-and-moody-mudskipper).

Comment: For 1) The WEEK after the last WEEK which has a STORE value should be treated as the exit WEEK. E.g., if last WEEK for STORE 227587 for PROD 13700023740 is 1630, then we can consider 1631 as the exit week for STORE 227587. Here again, the last possible WEEK for any PROD-STORE combination is 1739. Hope this clarifies.

Comment: alright these 2 aspects complexify the situation quite a bit. It would be great if you could add another example that include these aspects, integrate these comments in the question as well, and I'll try to take a look later today if no one else picks it up.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this should do it, if there's a mistake on your last row of expected output:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(Entry = !duplicated(STORE),
              Exit = !duplicated(STORE,fromLast = TRUE)) %>%
  group_by(PROD, WEEK) %>%
  summarize(Entry = sum(Entry),
            Exit= sum(Exit),
            Total = n()) %>%
  mutate(Exit = c(0,head(Exit,-1)))
# # A tibble: 4 x 5
# # Groups:   PROD [1]
#          PROD  WEEK Entry  Exit Total
#         <dbl> <int> <int> <dbl> <int>
# 1 13700023740  1534     5     0     5
# 2 13700023740  1535     3     1     7
# 3 13700023740  1536     6     3    10
# 4 13700023740  1537     7     5    12
```

**data**

```
df <- read.table(header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE,text="PROD           STORE         WEEK
13700023740   227587          1534
                 13700023740   227588          1534
                 13700023740   227589          1534
                 13700023740   227590          1534
                 13700023740   227591          1534
                 13700023740   227588          1535
                 13700023740   227589          1535
                 13700023740   227590          1535
                 13700023740   227591          1535
                 13700023740   227592          1535
                 13700023740   227593          1535
                 13700023740   227594          1535
                 13700023740   227591          1536
                 13700023740   227592          1536
                 13700023740   227593          1536
                 13700023740   227594          1536
                 13700023740   227595          1536
                 13700023740   227596          1536
                 13700023740   227597          1536
                 13700023740   227598          1536
                 13700023740   227599          1536
                 13700023740   227600          1536
                 13700023740   227596          1537
                 13700023740   227597          1537
                 13700023740   227598          1537
                 13700023740   227599          1537
                 13700023740   227600          1537
                 13700023740   227601          1537
                 13700023740   227602          1537
                 13700023740   227603          1537
                 13700023740   227604          1537
                 13700023740   227605          1537
                 13700023740   227606          1537
                 13700023740   227607          1537")
```